# Custom replacement matrix for edit distance in R

Tags: r, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

I need to compute the edit distance between two strings based on a custom cost function for replacements. For example, I want to specify different cost for replacing 'a' with 'b' than replacing 'a' with 'c'

Is there an R package that allows me to pass a custom cost matrix as an argument? If not, I will have to modify a package for this purpose, then which package do you think is good for implementing this kind of extension?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like `adist` in the `utils` package does this.

Comment: this is to assign different unit costs to different kind of operations. what I needed was a function of two characters that computes different costs for different character pairs. e.g insertion('a','b') = 2, insertion(d,e) = 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that there is no such package which is capable of doing what I needed. Therefore, I had to come up with my own solution to this problem by writing an R package (which is not indeed generic -easy to adapt for other applications) capable of doing what I need.

here it is for the curious -> https://github.com/aanilpala/r-trajectory-editdistance

Answer (score 0):

Now you can do this simply with the package [`lingdist`](https://github.com/fncokg/lingdist), which is:

- Fast enough, since it is written in C++ and supports multithreading.
- Easy enough, since you just need to pass a cost matrix to the function.

What's more, you can also check the detailed matching paths.